# Double-tap to zoom in PDF UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, pdf, uiscrollview, zooming

I have an "PDF Viewer" in my application. I use the `CGPDFDocumentRef` and `CGPDFPageRef` to show the PDF. To zoom in the PDF I use a `UIScrollView`.

I am already able to pinch-zoom in the UIScrollView but I also want to be able to double-tap to zoom.

Double tap with one finger takes you to different levels in the PDF until you hit the `maximumZoomLevel` and then be able to double-tap with two fingers to the `minimumZoomLevel`.

I haven't been able to find a solution on the Internet that shows you this in particular so I'm asking here. How could I accomplish this?

In viewDidLoad:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [doubleTap release];
```

Method:

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{      
    if(self.scrollView.zoomScale > self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale)
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale animated:YES]; 
    else 
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` with `numberOfTapsRequired` property after that in handle method (which you specify when alloc/init the recognizer) and use to use `– zoomToRect:animated:` or `– setZoomScale:animated:` on the view to zoom.

Edit: keep track on current zoom level to reverse the effect.

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried. But I can't get it to work while it should. Updated the question and added some code.